# Using awk how do I reprint a found pattern with a new line character?

Tags: awk, design-patterns, newline, gsub

I have a text file in the format of:

```
aaa: bcd;bcd;bcddd;aaa:bcd;bcd;bcd;
```

Where "bcd" can be any length of any characters, excluding `;` or `:`

What I want to do is print the text file in the format of:

```
aaa: bcd;bcd;bcddd;
aaa: bcd;bcd;bcd;
```

-etc-

My method of approach to this problem was to isolate a pattern of "`;...:`" and then reprint this pattern without the initial `;`

I concluded I would have to use awk's 'gsub' to do this, but have no idea how to replicate the pattern nor how to print the pattern again with this added new line character 1 character into my pattern.

Is this possible?
If not, can you please direct me in a way of tackling it?

Comment: Are you just trying to insert a newline after every third ';'?  Or is there more to it than that.

Comment: The amount of ";" is not consistent so unfortunately can't be as simple as "after every 3rd".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't quite be sure of the variability in the `aaa` or `bcd` parts; presumably, each one could be almost anything.

You should probably be looking for:

- a series of one or more non-colon, non-semicolon characters followed by colon,
- with one or more repeats of:

  - a series of one or more non-colon, non-semicolon characters followed by a semi-colon

That makes up the unit you want to match.

```
/[^:;]+:([^:;]+;)+/
```

With that, you can substitute what was found by the same followed by a newline, and then print the result.  The only trick is avoiding superfluous newlines.

#### Example script:

```
{
echo "aaa: bcd;bcd;bcddd;aaa:bcd;bcd;bcd;" 
echo "aaz: xcd;ycd;bczdd;baa:bed;bid;bud;"
} |
awk '{ gsub(/[^:;]+:([^:;]+;)+/, "&\n"); sub(/\n+$/, ""); print }'
```

#### Example output

```
aaa: bcd;bcd;bcddd;
aaa:bcd;bcd;bcd;
aaz: xcd;ycd;bczdd;
baa:bed;bid;bud;
```

---

Paraphrasing the question in a comment:

> Why does the regular expression not include the characters before a colon (which is what it's intended to do, but I don't understand why)? I don't understand what "breaks" or ends the regex.

As I tried to explain at the top, you're looking for what we can call 'words', meaning sequences of characters that are neither a colon nor a semicolon.  In the regex, that is `[^:;]+`, meaning one or more (`+`) of the negated character class — one or more non-colon, non-semicolon characters.

Let's pretend that spaces in a regex are not significant.  We can space out the regex like this:

```
    / [^:;]+ : ( [^:;]+ ; ) + /
```

The slashes simply mark the ends, of course.  The first cluster is a word; then there's a colon.  Then there is a group enclosed in parentheses, tagged with a `+` at the end.  That means that the contents of the group must occur at least once and may occur any number of times more than that.  What's inside the group?  Well, a word followed by a semicolon.  It doesn't have to be the same word each time, but there does have to be a word there.  If something can occur zero or more times, then you use a `*` in place of the `+`, of course.

The key to the regex stopping is that the `aaa:` in the middle of the first line does not consist of a word followed by a semicolon; it is a word followed by a colon.  So, the regex has to stop before that because the `aaa:` doesn't match the group.  The `gsub()` therefore finds the first sequence, and replaces that text with the same material and a newline (that's the `"&\n"`, of course).  It (`gsub()`) then resumes its search directly after the end of the replacement material, and — lo and behold — there is a word followed by a colon and some words followed by semicolons, so there's a second match to be replaced with its original material plus a newline.

I think that `$0` must contain the newline at the end of the line.  Therefore, without the `sub()` to remove a trailing newlines, the `print` (implictly of `$0` with a newline) generated a blank line I didn't want in the output, so I removed the extraneous newline(s).  The newline at the end of `$0` would not be matched by the `gsub()` because it is not followed by a colon or semicolon.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly, except for some reason in my text file it has one extra "space" of white space, yet if I create a text file using the input you used it doesn't. I'll just sed it out that's no big deal. I understand basically everything except why the regular expression does not include the characters before a colon. (Which is its intended purpose yes, but I don't understand why).
I get that you have grouped a semi colon in with [^;:] but dont understand what "breaks" or ends the regex.

What I am trying to get my head around is the logic of your gsub

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
 awk '{gsub(/[^;:]*:/,"\n&");sub(/^\n/,"");gsub(/: */,": ")}1' file
```

1. Prepend a newline (`\n`) to any string not containing a `;` or a `:` followed by a `:`
2. Remove any newline prepended to the start of line.
3. Replace any `:` followed by none or many spaces with a `:` followed by a single space.
4. Print all lines.

Or this:

```
 sed 's/;\([^;:]*: *\)/;\n\1 /g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it in awk, but with sed this does what I think you want:

```
$ nl='
'
$ sed "s/\([^;]*:\)/\\${nl}\1/g" input
```

The first command sets the shell variable $nl to the string containing a single new line.  Some versions of sed allow you to use \n inside the replacement string, but not all allow that.  This keeps any whitespace that appears after the final ; and puts it at the start of the line.  To get rid of that, you can do

```
$ sed "s/\([^;]*:\)/\\${nl}\1/g; s/\n */\\$nl/g" input
```

Answer (score 0):

Ordinary awk gsub() and sub() don't allow you to specify components in the replacement strings  Gnu awk - "gawk" - supplies "gensub()" which would allow "gensub(/(;) (.+:)/,"\1\n\2","g")"